# Android Installation Blocked Message

Tags: android, installation, warnings

I have an android application, which was working properly since almost 1 month ago. I have not changed anything since a long time ago but a warning message showed up on users screen just before installing my application, saying that my application is tracking user data with a dialog containing "OK", and "Install anyway" button.

I remove my own google analytics and release a new version, which has two ad SDK used by lots of applications in my country without facing any problem and the problem still exist.
[link to the warning image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ij6rO.jpg)

Comment: Are you using location tracking in your application without having created a Privacy Policy first? https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google asks developers to publish a Privacy Policy if their apps handle user data. You can find this setting in your Google Developer Console.

[Developer Privacy and Security](https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security/)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to disable the ad SDK? if it works you have the answer, if it doesn't test it also on other device to be sure the problem is not just yours.